# minimax tic-tac-toe algorithm wrongly always puts the "X"or "O" in the next available place

Tags: java, algorithm, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I am trying to create a tic-tac-toe game that responds to the player with the minimax algorithm. It is not working. It just puts the "X"or "O" in the next available place. (If 0,0 is is not null then it goes to 0,1 and then 0,2.) I do not understand why. What am I doing wrong?

The code:

```
public static int minimax( String[][] arr,String AI,String human,boolean turn) {
    if (end(arr))
    {
        String cheak = win_check(arr);
        return win_value(cheak,AI,human);
    }
    if (turn)
    {
        int best_score = -2;
        int score;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int f = 0; f < 3; f++)
            {
                {
                    if (arr[i][f] == "")
                    {
                        arr[i][f] = AI;
                        score = minimax(arr, AI, human, false);
                        arr[i][f] = "";
                        if ((best_score < score))
                        {
                            best_score = score;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return best_score;
    }
    //function that does the best move using the minimax algorithm
    public static void best_move (String arr [][],String AI,String human)
{
 int move_score;
 int best_move_score = -2;
 int moves [] =new int[2];
 for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
 {
     for (int f=0;f<arr.length;f++)
     {
         if(arr[i][f] == "")
         {
             move_score = minimax(arr,AI,human,true);
             if(move_score>best_move_score)
             {
                 best_move_score = move_score;
                 moves[0] = i;
                 moves[1]= f;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Hi adi, welcome to StackOverflow. "it's just not working" can cover a lot of ground, can you be more specific? Is there an error, is something freezing, is an unexpected move being made? Including a section about the expected/intended behavior vs. the actual behavior can help to debug the problem.

Comment: Your explanation of what is wrong is not clear, please edit. Use enough words & sentences. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) Runtime find & show input & output up to the 1st point that doesn't have the program in the state you expect. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: improved title, language, format. asker still needs to give a MRE, including explaining the problem more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I have created this game in C#, you could take the inspiration from here...

**TicToaToeHeart**

```
class TicToaToeHeart
{
    //  A  | B  | C
    // -------------
    //  D  | E  | F
    // -------------
    //  G  | H  |I

    public static string[] Strike = { "ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "ADG", "BEH", "CFI", "CEG", "AEI" };

    public static string[] PossibleMoves = { "AB","AC","AD","AE","AG","AI",
                                              "BC","BE","BH",
                                              "CE","CG","CI","CF",
                                              "DG","DE","DF",
                                              "EF","EG","EH","EI",
                                              "FI",
                                              "GH","GI","GC",
                                              "HI"
                                            };
    public static string[] RemainingMoves = { "C","B","G","I","D","E",
                                              "A","H","E",
                                              "G","E","F","I",
                                              "A","F","E",
                                              "D","C","B","A",
                                              "C",
                                              "I","H","E",
                                              "G"
                                            };
}
```

**Game**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TIC_TAC_TOE
{
    public partial class Game : Form
    {
        private string userToken = string.Empty;
        private string userClicked = "";
        private string pcClicked = "";
        public Game()
        {
            InitializeComponent2();
            textBox1.Focus();
            comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            comboBox1.Items.Add("X");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("O");
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        private void ButtonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StartGame("0", "0");
        }

        private void ButtonA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateUserButtonDetails(buttonA, "A");
        }

        private void ButtonB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateUserButtonDetails(buttonB, "B");
        }

        private void ButtonC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateUserButtonDetails(buttonC, "C");
        }

        private void ButtonD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateUserButtonDetails(buttonD, "D");
        }

        private void ButtonE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateUserButtonDetails(buttonE, "E");
        }

        private void ButtonF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateUserButtonDetails(buttonF, "F");
        }

        private void ButtonG_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateUserButtonDetails(buttonG, "G");
        }

        private void ButtonH_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateUserButtonDetails(buttonH, "H");
        }

        private void ButtonI_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateUserButtonDetails(buttonI, "I");
        }

        private void UpdateUserButtonDetails(Button button, string selectedButton)
        {
            button.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;
            button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            button.Text = userToken;
            button.Enabled = false;
            userClicked += selectedButton;
            ComputerTurn();
        }

        private string getPCToken()
        {
            return ("XO").Replace(userToken, "");
        }

        private void ComputerTurn()
        {
            CheckScore(userClicked, true);
            {
                if (CheckForPcWinChance(pcClicked, false) == false)
                    CheckForPcWinChance(userClicked, true);
            }
        }

        public bool SelectToken(string token)
        {
            if (SelectableTokenForPc(token) == false)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (CheckForPcWinChance(pcClicked, false) == false)
                    SelectButton(token);
                return true;
            }
        }

        private bool CheckForPcWinChance(string pcClick, bool check)
        {
            bool flag = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < Token.PossibleMoves.Length; i++)
            {
                string key = Token.PossibleMoves[i];
                flag = true;
                for (int j = 0; j < key.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (!(pcClick.IndexOf(key[j]) >= 0))
                    {
                        flag = false;
                    }
                }
                if (flag)
                {
                    if (SelectableTokenForPc(Token.RemainingMoves[i]) == false)
                        continue;
                    else
                    {
                        SelectButton(Token.RemainingMoves[i]);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!flag && check)
            {
                string allToken = "ABCDEFGHI";
                Random r = new Random();
                while (true)
                {
                    int index = r.Next(0, 9);
                    if (SelectToken(allToken[index].ToString()) == false)
                        continue;
                    else
                        break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void SelectButton(string selectedButton)
        {
            switch (selectedButton)
            {
                case "A":
                    {
                        UpdatePcButtonDetails(buttonA, selectedButton);
                    }
                    break;
                case "B":
                    {
                        UpdatePcButtonDetails(buttonB, selectedButton);
                    }
                    break;
                case "C":
                    {
                        UpdatePcButtonDetails(buttonC, selectedButton);
                    }
                    break;
                case "D":
                    {
                        UpdatePcButtonDetails(buttonD, selectedButton);
                    }
                    break;
                case "E":
                    {
                        UpdatePcButtonDetails(buttonE, selectedButton);
                    }
                    break;
                case "F":
                    {
                        UpdatePcButtonDetails(buttonF, selectedButton);
                    }
                    break;
                case "G":
                    {
                        UpdatePcButtonDetails(buttonG, selectedButton);
                    }
                    break;
                case "H":
                    {
                        UpdatePcButtonDetails(buttonH, selectedButton);
                    }
                    break;
                case "I":
                    {
                        UpdatePcButtonDetails(buttonI, selectedButton);
                    }
                    break;

            }
            CheckScore(pcClicked, false);
        }

        private void UpdatePcButtonDetails(Button button, string selectedButton)
        {
            button.BackColor = Color.Red;
            button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            button.Text = getPCToken();
            pcClicked += selectedButton;
            button.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void CheckScore(string token, bool user)
        {
            foreach (string s in Token.Strike)
            {
                bool flag = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (!(token.IndexOf(s[i]) >= 0))
                    {
                        flag = false;
                    }
                }
                if (flag)
                {
                    if (user)
                    {
                        label5.Text = ((Convert.ToInt32(label5.Text)) + 10) + "";
                        MessageBox.Show(label1.Text + " WON", "Result", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        label8.Text = ((Convert.ToInt32(label8.Text)) + 10) + "";
                        MessageBox.Show("PC WON", "Result", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }

                    StartGame(label8.Text, label5.Text);
                    break;
                }
                if (userClicked.Length + pcClicked.Length == 9)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Game Draw", "Result", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    StartGame(label8.Text, label5.Text);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        private bool SelectableTokenForPc(string newToken)
        {
            if (userClicked.IndexOf(newToken) >= 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (pcClicked.IndexOf(newToken) >= 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        private void StartGame(string pcScore, string userScore)
        {
            string name = textBox1.Text;
            name = name.Trim();
            if (name.Equals(""))
            {
                return;
            }
            userClicked = "";
            pcClicked = "";
            userToken = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            this.Controls.Clear();
            InitializeComponent();
            label1.Text = name;
            label4.Text = "Pc : ";
            label5.Text = userScore;
            label8.Text = pcScore;
        }

        private void ReStartGameButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StartGame("0", "0");
        }

        private void ContinueButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StartGame(label8.Text, label5.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[github code link](https://github.com/narottamgoyal/tic.tac.toe.game)